# How to generate a list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Python 3.4. I want to generate a list that contains integers, relating to the corresponding hex by the algorithm:

```
hex-view:

000000 // first value in list
010101 // second
020202 // third

.....
FFFFFF // end.
```

After, I just use int:

```
[int(x) for x in hex_list].
```

How to generate a hex list? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much work.

```
[x * 0x010101 for x in range(256)]
```

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: Why, when the asker is just going to turn around and call `int()`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that.  Okay then. I assumed the end result will be list of hex.

Answer (score 3):

To generate the initial hex list:

```
l = ['0x'+format(i, '06x') for i in range(0, 16777216, 65793)]
```

To convert it to int:

```
i = list(map(lambda x:int(x,0), l))
```

Thus `l` looks like:

```
['0x000000', '0x010101', '0x020202', '0x030303', '0x040404', '0x050505', '0x060606', '0x070707', '0x080808', '0x090909', '0x0a0a0a', '0x0b0b0b', '0x0c0c0c', '0x0d0d0d', '0x0e0e0e', '0x0f0f0f', '0x101010', '0x111111', '0x121212', '0x131313', '0x141414', '0x151515', '0x161616', '0x171717', '0x181818', '0x191919', '0x1a1a1a', '0x1b1b1b', '0x1c1c1c', '0x1d1d1d', '0x1e1e1e', '0x1f1f1f', '0x202020', '0x212121', '0x222222', '0x232323', '0x242424', '0x252525', '0x262626', '0x272727', '0x282828', '0x292929', '0x2a2a2a', '0x2b2b2b', '0x2c2c2c', '0x2d2d2d', '0x2e2e2e', '0x2f2f2f', '0x303030', '0x313131', '0x323232', '0x333333', '0x343434', '0x353535', '0x363636', '0x373737', '0x383838', '0x393939', '0x3a3a3a', '0x3b3b3b', '0x3c3c3c', '0x3d3d3d', '0x3e3e3e', '0x3f3f3f', '0x404040', '0x414141', '0x424242', '0x434343', '0x444444', '0x454545', '0x464646', '0x474747', '0x484848', '0x494949', '0x4a4a4a', '0x4b4b4b', '0x4c4c4c', '0x4d4d4d', '0x4e4e4e', '0x4f4f4f', '0x505050', '0x515151', '0x525252', '0x535353', '0x545454', '0x555555', '0x565656', '0x575757', '0x585858', '0x595959', '0x5a5a5a', '0x5b5b5b', '0x5c5c5c', '0x5d5d5d', '0x5e5e5e', '0x5f5f5f', '0x606060', '0x616161', '0x626262', '0x636363', '0x646464', '0x656565', '0x666666', '0x676767', '0x686868', '0x696969', '0x6a6a6a', '0x6b6b6b', '0x6c6c6c', '0x6d6d6d', '0x6e6e6e', '0x6f6f6f', '0x707070', '0x717171', '0x727272', '0x737373', '0x747474', '0x757575', '0x767676', '0x777777', '0x787878', '0x797979', '0x7a7a7a', '0x7b7b7b', '0x7c7c7c', '0x7d7d7d', '0x7e7e7e', '0x7f7f7f', '0x808080', '0x818181', '0x828282', '0x838383', '0x848484', '0x858585', '0x868686', '0x878787', '0x888888', '0x898989', '0x8a8a8a', '0x8b8b8b', '0x8c8c8c', '0x8d8d8d', '0x8e8e8e', '0x8f8f8f', '0x909090', '0x919191', '0x929292', '0x939393', '0x949494', '0x959595', '0x969696', '0x979797', '0x989898', '0x999999', '0x9a9a9a', '0x9b9b9b', '0x9c9c9c', '0x9d9d9d', '0x9e9e9e', '0x9f9f9f', '0xa0a0a0', '0xa1a1a1', '0xa2a2a2', '0xa3a3a3', '0xa4a4a4', '0xa5a5a5', '0xa6a6a6', '0xa7a7a7', '0xa8a8a8', '0xa9a9a9', '0xaaaaaa', '0xababab', '0xacacac', '0xadadad', '0xaeaeae', '0xafafaf', '0xb0b0b0', '0xb1b1b1', '0xb2b2b2', '0xb3b3b3', '0xb4b4b4', '0xb5b5b5', '0xb6b6b6', '0xb7b7b7', '0xb8b8b8', '0xb9b9b9', '0xbababa', '0xbbbbbb', '0xbcbcbc', '0xbdbdbd', '0xbebebe', '0xbfbfbf', '0xc0c0c0', '0xc1c1c1', '0xc2c2c2', '0xc3c3c3', '0xc4c4c4', '0xc5c5c5', '0xc6c6c6', '0xc7c7c7', '0xc8c8c8', '0xc9c9c9', '0xcacaca', '0xcbcbcb', '0xcccccc', '0xcdcdcd', '0xcecece', '0xcfcfcf', '0xd0d0d0', '0xd1d1d1', '0xd2d2d2', '0xd3d3d3', '0xd4d4d4', '0xd5d5d5', '0xd6d6d6', '0xd7d7d7', '0xd8d8d8', '0xd9d9d9', '0xdadada', '0xdbdbdb', '0xdcdcdc', '0xdddddd', '0xdedede', '0xdfdfdf', '0xe0e0e0', '0xe1e1e1', '0xe2e2e2', '0xe3e3e3', '0xe4e4e4', '0xe5e5e5', '0xe6e6e6', '0xe7e7e7', '0xe8e8e8', '0xe9e9e9', '0xeaeaea', '0xebebeb', '0xececec', '0xededed', '0xeeeeee', '0xefefef', '0xf0f0f0', '0xf1f1f1', '0xf2f2f2', '0xf3f3f3', '0xf4f4f4', '0xf5f5f5', '0xf6f6f6', '0xf7f7f7', '0xf8f8f8', '0xf9f9f9', '0xfafafa', '0xfbfbfb', '0xfcfcfc', '0xfdfdfd', '0xfefefe', '0xffffff']
```

and `i` looks like:

```
[0, 65793, 131586, 197379, 263172, 328965, 394758, 460551, 526344, 592137, 657930, 723723, 789516, 855309, 921102, 986895, 1052688, 1118481, 1184274, 1250067, 1315860, 1381653, 1447446, 1513239, 1579032, 1644825, 1710618, 1776411, 1842204, 1907997, 1973790, 2039583, 2105376, 2171169, 2236962, 2302755, 2368548, 2434341, 2500134, 2565927, 2631720, 2697513, 2763306, 2829099, 2894892, 2960685, 3026478, 3092271, 3158064, 3223857, 3289650, 3355443, 3421236, 3487029, 3552822, 3618615, 3684408, 3750201, 3815994, 3881787, 3947580, 4013373, 4079166, 4144959, 4210752, 4276545, 4342338, 4408131, 4473924, 4539717, 4605510, 4671303, 4737096, 4802889, 4868682, 4934475, 5000268, 5066061, 5131854, 5197647, 5263440, 5329233, 5395026, 5460819, 5526612, 5592405, 5658198, 5723991, 5789784, 5855577, 5921370, 5987163, 6052956, 6118749, 6184542, 6250335, 6316128, 6381921, 6447714, 6513507, 6579300, 6645093, 6710886, 6776679, 6842472, 6908265, 6974058, 7039851, 7105644, 7171437, 7237230, 7303023, 7368816, 7434609, 7500402, 7566195, 7631988, 7697781, 7763574, 7829367, 7895160, 7960953, 8026746, 8092539, 8158332, 8224125, 8289918, 8355711, 8421504, 8487297, 8553090, 8618883, 8684676, 8750469, 8816262, 8882055, 8947848, 9013641, 9079434, 9145227, 9211020, 9276813, 9342606, 9408399, 9474192, 9539985, 9605778, 9671571, 9737364, 9803157, 9868950, 9934743, 10000536, 10066329, 10132122, 10197915, 10263708, 10329501, 10395294, 10461087, 10526880, 10592673, 10658466, 10724259, 10790052, 10855845, 10921638, 10987431, 11053224, 11119017, 11184810, 11250603, 11316396, 11382189, 11447982, 11513775, 11579568, 11645361, 11711154, 11776947, 11842740, 11908533, 11974326, 12040119, 12105912, 12171705, 12237498, 12303291, 12369084, 12434877, 12500670, 12566463, 12632256, 12698049, 12763842, 12829635, 12895428, 12961221, 13027014, 13092807, 13158600, 13224393, 13290186, 13355979, 13421772, 13487565, 13553358, 13619151, 13684944, 13750737, 13816530, 13882323, 13948116, 14013909, 14079702, 14145495, 14211288, 14277081, 14342874, 14408667, 14474460, 14540253, 14606046, 14671839, 14737632, 14803425, 14869218, 14935011, 15000804, 15066597, 15132390, 15198183, 15263976, 15329769, 15395562, 15461355, 15527148, 15592941, 15658734, 15724527, 15790320, 15856113, 15921906, 15987699, 16053492, 16119285, 16185078, 16250871, 16316664, 16382457, 16448250, 16514043, 16579836, 16645629, 16711422, 16777215]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hex()` built-in function instead of `int()` in order to convert your integer number to hex.

Answer (score 1):

just 2 line of code:

```
for i in range(0,256):
    print('%02X%02X%02X' % (i,i,i), sep="")
```

Output:

```
000000 010101 020202 030303 040404 050505 060606 070707 080808 090909 
0A0A0A 0B0B0B 0C0C0C 0D0D0D 0E0E0E 0F0F0F ....
```